# Function in useEffect runs once whereas I want to run concurrently

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array with `length === 4` **Please note that the length may vary based on some outside parameters**. I want to run a function that generates input fields according to the length of my array onComponentDidMount using useEffect.

```js
const [blankField, setBlankField] = useState([dynamicFields]); // This adds the input fields with the required data

const legs = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]; // the length of legs[] may vary in number

const addField = () => {
        setBlankField([...blankField, [...dynamicFields]]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (legs) {
            legs.map(leg => {
                console.log(leg);
                return addField();
            });
        }
    }, []);

blankFields.map(......);
```

I want it to generate as many fields as the length of the array immediately the component mounts.

Comment: What is the point of using the loop? Are you trying to do some visual delay? Do you just want to present the number of legs?

Comment: What do you mean by `varies from an action performed previously on the application`?

Comment: @NileshSingh it means the array length can be 4, 10, 11 or what ever number. I have no control over that. I just want to generate fields that match the array length number onComponentMount

Comment: Do we have an idea as to where we get this array from?

Comment: @NileshSingh Its coming from my redux store. The array isn't the problem. I'm using as a parameter to generate enough fields.
Imagine a scenario where I want to book slots for an event and I select 10 people (*this is `legs`)* are attending, I want to be able to generate enough input fields in the next step that match the number so I can enter the names of the individual 10 people who are attending.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `[]` as `dependency of useEffect`, it only runs once when the component is mounted. Instead write it as,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (legs) {
      legs.map(leg => {
        setCount([count + 1]);
        console.log(count, leg);
        return addField();
       });
    }
  }, [legs.length]);
```

Now, it will trigger for every change in `length`

Comment: Even with this, it still generates 2 fields only.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the issue because the value of legs.length never changes.